# .NetCore 2.0 building https crawler prompt System.PlatformNotSupportedException

Tags: curl, .net-core, libcurl

I'm building a console application using .NetCore 2.0

This application is making a REST call for a server which running on "https"， but when i try run it under MacOs high sierra, got these prompt

> Unhandled Exception: System.PlatformNotSupportedException: The
>   handler does not support custom handling of certificates with this
>   combination of libcurl (7.54.0) and its SSL backend
>   ("LibreSSL/2.0.20").

the code can run perfect under CentOS after i upgrade libcurl-openssl, is any solution for MacOS?

thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you able to make the same call via the `curl` command line tool? Did you maybe install a custom libcurl via homebrew at some point?

Comment: i already use brew to update libcurl to 7.56 (it looks the lastest version i can got) but its still can't pass...

Comment: I answered something similar here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49367658/841344