# DotNet core 2.0 on MacOS gets libcurl and ssl error triggered by httpclient when using couchbase dotnet sdk

Tags: macos, ssl, curl, .net-core, couchbase

I am developing an Dotnet core 2.x(actually using 2.1.4, latest release when I'm writing this) web api project, in order to use couchbase as my database server, I need to use the couchbase SDK. The sdk states that it supports DotNet core 2.x.

After a very basic setup and I just want to test the connectivity, I keep getting this error.

> HttpRequestException: The handler does not support custom handling of certificates with this combination of libcurl (7.54.0) and its SSL backend ("LibreSSL/2.0.20").

I thought this is a issue with the couchbase SDK, but after some research, I found it is about the macOS built-in openssl and curl does not support certain behavior. Here are some reference:

[.NET Core, OSX, libcurl, and OpenSSL](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2017/09/28/net-core-osx-libcurl-openssl/)

[Couchbase dotnet SDK OSX libcurl error](https://forums.couchbase.com/t/couchbase-dotnet-sdk-osx-libcurl-error/12238)

after some more research, it turns out that dotnet core 2.0 should no longer suffer from the MacOS related issue...But why am I still getting this?

Is there any workaround like telling HttpClient to use brew version of curl?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Steps to Use Socket HTTP Handler

Here's what I needed to do to get this to work:

- Install .NET Core SDK [2.1.xxx-preview](https://github.com/dotnet/cli#installers-and-binaries)
- Update Project `AspNetCore.All` Reference
- Add Package Source to `NuGet.Config`
- Set Environment Variable

### Install .NET Core SDK [2.1.xxx-preview]

Download and install [macOs installer](https://dotnetcli.blob.core.windows.net/dotnet/Sdk/master/dotnet-sdk-latest-osx-x64.pkg)

### Update Project `AspNetCore.All` Reference

Update package reference to:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.1.0-preview1-final" />
```

### Add Package Source to `NuGet.Config`

Update `~/.nuget/NuGet/NuGet.Config` and add another package source:

```
<add key="dotnet-core" value="https://dotnet.myget.org/F/dotnet-core/api/v3/index.json" />
```

I needed to do this because I was getting a NuGet error:
`error NU1102: Unable to find package Microsoft.AspNetCore.All with version (>= 2.1.0)`.

### Set Environment Variable

In my `Startup.cs` I set an environment variable:

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("DOTNET_SYSTEM_NET_HTTP_USESOCKETSHTTPHANDLER", "true");
```

### What We're Doing

With 2.1 dotnet will incorporate its own Socket Handler which bypasses OS specific ones and so we can avoid the macOS issues. In preview-1 we still have to manually opt-in:
https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClientHandler.cs

But soon in preview-2 it'll be on by default:
https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/27821

#### Previous post

I've been investigating the same issue this morning and I currently don't think there's a clear solution. Dotnet Core 2.x does not resolve the issue for the Couchbase SDK, though I think using `HttpClient` outside of Couchbase is fine (haven't tested this).

As of Couchbase SDK Version 2.5.8 (17 March 2018) this is still a known issue:
https://developer.couchbase.com/server/other-products/release-notes-archives/dotnet-sdk

Actual issue link:
https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/NCBC-1296

In the forums, see:

- https://forums.couchbase.com/t/couchbase-dotnet-sdk-osx-libcurl-error/12238
- https://forums.couchbase.com/t/platformnotsupportedexception-when-querying-from-net-core-2-0-on-macos/15490/6

I'll post back if I find a working solution.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive analysis and solution, great to hear this issue will be addressed in V2.1. Now I'm working in a win10 vm for this project, will probably wait for the release version.